# AWK command to input new csv column

Tags: awk, jq

I have a .csv that has two columns already. I have a percentage.txt file with 1 column of data which I would like to input as a whole column into the csv @ column 3..

I cannot seem to work out a command ..

This is what I have and is not working

```
awk -F, '{getline f1 <"dels_20210508.csv" ;print f1,$3}' OFS=, percent.txt
```

My desired output would be to the original csv would be the following (col3-data, will come from the percent.txt first column)

| col1-data | col2-data | col3-data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| col1-data | col2-data | col3-data |
| col1-data | col2-data | col3-data |
| col1-data | col2-data | col3-data |

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: How your question is related to tag `jq` (which is tool for working with JSON data, not CSV)?

Comment: Have you considered using `paste`?  If percentage.txt is sufficiently simple and if you really want to use awk, I'd suggest `print $0 "," f1`

Comment: @triplee - Please consider reopening this Q or at least providing a link to question which addresses the distinct issue here - adding a non-CSV column to a CSV file while preserving correctness as a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `percentage.txt` is a valid one-column CSV file, you would have to make it "CSV-safe" before simply pasting it to the CSV file. Since you included [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) as a tag, it may be of interest to show how this could be done with jq.

Assuming the .csv file is valid CSV and that `percentage.txt` and the .csv file are properly matched w.r.t. headers, you could use `jq` and `paste` together, along the lines of:

```
paste -d, dels_20210508.csv <(jq -Rr '[.]|@csv' percent.txt)
```